# Automatically reload cached objects after varnish xkey.softpurge()

Tags: varnish

I need to automatically refresh/fetch again objects I invalidated with `xkey.softpurge()` so that varnish always has a cached version in memory. How is this possible?

I am doing a restart in `vcl_purge` but this does not seem to be executed when doing an xkey purge.

```
sub vcl_purge {
    set req.method = "GET";
    return(restart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A single xkey (soft)purge operation will quick from the storage an undefined number of objets. It's not possible to trigger threads to refresh each kicked object.

This is similar to normal purges, but usually purging a URL kicks a single object from the storage. That's why the restart works as expected. In any case, a single purge could kick multiple objects (e.g. Vary responses) and the restart will only refresh one of the variants.